# Finding greatest sum of k values divisible by m?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to get an algorithm to find the different ways of combining a set of numbers so that they are divisible by 5.

For example, the array is `[9,7,6,8,0,1,4]`, I'm trying to find the largest combination of 4 numbers out of the array that is divisible by 5 but I have no idea how to find all of the combinations of 4 separately and then add them up and then find out if its divisible by 5, in addition to that, there is always a number that has to be included in the set of 4 that is dictated by the input.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Is there any particular reason you can't brute force it?

Comment: Do you have to find all the subsets that sum to 5 or the largest subset that sums to 5? Or the subset with the largest sum that's divisible by 5? Or the subset of 4 elements that has the largest sum? Something else? Also, what number always has to be included?

Comment: I have to find the subset with the largest sum that's divisible by 5. The number that has to be included is dependent on the input and the array used is just an arbitrary one, it could be anything.

Comment: Define "Combination" - addition, subtraction ... multiplication? The modulous operand will be of great value here  and this may help too... http://www.mathwords.com/c/combination_formula.htm

Comment: I don't have to find the number of sets, I have to find the subset that is the largest and also divisible by 5.

Comment: @TravisSharp *"... then add them up and then find out if its divisible by 5"* So, addition. But the OP's difficulty is finding combinations in the first place.

Comment: @user3196598 Finding combinations of values in a set is a pretty common thing to do. Search for "Java combination algorithms". Once you actually *have* your combinations, then its up to you to go through, add them up and find the ones that meet your criteria. But in any case you have two separate operations to perform: 1) Find combinations of numbers, 2) Test if those combinations meet your requirements (sum of the values is divisible by 5) and keep track of the longest one that does.

Comment: @JasonC Ahh - got it. Do you think that some sort of recursive function that essentially traverses the set like a graph and performs the math at each step will do it or would there be a better, more efficient, way to do it?

Comment: @TravisSharp For a set of the size in the OP's example, it's not really going to matter. For larger sets, though, I would evaluate the combinations as they are being generated (either recursively or iteratively, whatever the case may be) to avoid having to store every combination in memory first -- plus, it's probably simpler to implement it that way anyways. I described these as two separate operations because they are essentially independent tasks, but they can still be done at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **C++** implementation of my dynamic programming approach.
I am sure you can make a java version for yourself.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_NUM = 10000, inf = (1<<30);

bool seen[MAX_NUM][5][5];
int nums[MAX_NUM], dp[MAX_NUM][5][5], N;

int calc(int pos, int taken, int mod)
{
    if(taken == 4)
    {
        if(mod) return -inf;
        return 0;
    }
    if(pos==N) return -inf;

    int &ret = dp[pos][taken][mod];
    bool &isSeen = seen[pos][taken][mod];

    if(isSeen) return ret;
    isSeen = true;
    return ret = max( calc(pos+1, taken+1, (mod+nums[pos])%5 )+nums[pos], calc(pos+1,taken,mod) );
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for(int i = 0;i<N;++i) scanf("%d",&nums[i]);

    memset(seen,0,sizeof(seen));
    printf("%d\n",calc(0,0,0));
    return 0;
}
```

My solution keeps track of the current number i am working with (pos), numbers i have taken so far (taken), the sum off all the taken integers % 5 (mod). Keeping these information's i am trying to maximize the sum of taken integeres where mod is equal to 0.

**If there are no such 4 numbers you will get a number less than zero.**